Batch Trouble using items in an Array where I am passing array items as parameters
Similar question to Echo batch file arrays using a variable for the index? I cannot seem to get items into my array. Code:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /A i=0
for %%X in (%*) do (
  set /A i+=1
  echo i=!i!
  echo %%X
  if !i!==1 (
    set rootpath=%%~X
  ) else if !i!==2 (
    set Manifest=%%~X
  ) else (
    set Environments[!i! - 2]=%%X
  )
)

When I try to use Environments array it comes up blank.
For my 3rd and 4th parameters I am passing "server,database" combinations so the output is:
...
i=3
"server1,db1"
i=4
"server2,db2"
...

When I try to echo say:
echo E1=!Environments[1]!

or
echo E1=%Environments[1]%

both return blank:
E1=

Where have I gone wrong in my code.
I am expecting:
E1="server1,db1"


You appear to be creating two variables %Environments[3 - 2]% to expand as "server1,db1" and %Environments[4 - 2]% to expand as "server2,db2". If you want %Environments[1]% and %Environments[2]%, i.e. perform arithmetic, you would certainly require to repeat your use of the /A option with Set.

You lost me. /A is for arithmetic, I am just setting an array to string values as you can pass in unlimited "server,database" parameters. I use the Environments variable in a function call later on where I call OSQL.

3 - 2 is arithmetic?? But I thought that would just work??

later on I call:
for %%c in (%Environments%) do call :RunScript %file% %%c
First line of RunScript I have an echo RunScript but it never gets there and the batch file just ends

R u are a genius thanks I used an intermediate variable set j = !i! + 1 then used !j!

Also, unless you aren't telling us something important, (like you will always be passing an unknown numer of one or more environments), why are you doing it like that anyhow? What is wrong with just 1. If Not "%~1" == "" Set "rootpath=%~1", 2. If Not "%~2" == "" Set "Manifest=%~2", 3. If Not "%~3" == "" Set "Environments[1]=%~3", and 4. If Not "%~4" == "" Set "Environments[2]=%~4". Even if you were passing an unknown number of environments, you still wouldn't need the array for %1 and %2, which are clearly fixed position.

Yes parameters 1 and 2 are fixed then unlimited after that.
Anyhow my echo works now after use of the second variable but now my "for %%c in (%Environments%) do call :RunScript %file% %%c" still not working!

And yes I could use your idea and start my loop at 2.

Here's an alternative, which works only if you pass every argument doublequoted, as you should.
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
If "%~3" == "" Exit /B
Set "rootpath=%~1"
Set "Manifest=%~2"
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('(Set Environments[^) 2^>NUL') Do Set "%%G="
Set "i=0"
For /F Tokens^=^4^,*^ Delims^=^" %%G In (%*) Do For %%I In ("%%~H") Do (Set /A i += 1
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For %%J In (!i!) Do (EndLocal
        Set "Environments[%%J]=%%~I"))
Set Environments[
Pause

Essentially what it does is, it works with all arguments after the second, (so the third argument becomes the first), and in doing so, means that no additional calculations are required.
You'll notice that line three simply exits the script if at least three arguments are not passed. Line six ensures that there are no pre-defined variables named beginning with the string Environments[. Delayed variable expansion is only enabled where required, preserving any possible ! characters in your argument strings. The last two lines are included just to show you what was defined. Finally, you should also note that I have deliberately removed any enclosing doublequotes from the expanded variable values. If those require quotes in use, you should quote the variable itself, i.e. "%VarName%", not its value content.

How about
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET /a i=-1

:loop
IF %i%==-1 SET "rootpath=%~1"&GOTO donesetting
IF %i%==0  SET "manifest=%~1"&GOTO donesetting
SET "environments[%i%]=%~1"
:donesetting
SET /a i+=1
SHIFT
IF "%~1" neq "" GOTO loop

SET root
SET mani
SET env

GOTO :EOF

Note: starting i at -1 so testing -1,0 for the first 2 elements, remaining elements are i=index_in_environments_array
Note: this shifts all arguments "off of the command line", so further reference to %n will be avaluated as empty. %* will contain the full list, however.
If this is a concern, then
call :alabelinsertedbeforethefirstseti %*

would leave the original argument list in place.

A simpler method (with NO if's):
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "params=%*"
for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in ("%params:,=^,%") do (
   set rootpath=%%~a
   set Manifest=%%~b

   set /A i=0
   for %%X in (%%c) do (
     set /A i+=1
     echo i=!i!
     echo %%X
     set Environments[!i!]=%%X
   )

)

ECHO ===========
SET ENV

Example:
> test.bat "thePath" "theManifest" "server,db1" "server,db2"

Output:
i=1
"server,db1"
i=2
"server,db2"
===========
Environments[1]="server,db1"
Environments[2]="server,db2"

